# Why the time is not printing the actual time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to verify the wait time with below code but the output is printing the same time again even after a min or so

Used `time.sleep(60)` and `ctime()` function in time module of python

```
import time

print("Local Time: ",time.ctime(seconds))
time.sleep(60)
print("Local Time: ",time.ctime(seconds))
```

Actual output is :

```
Local Time:  Thu Dec 27 21:19:29 2018
Local Time:  Thu Dec 27 21:19:29 2018
```

Expected output is:

```
Local Time:  Thu Dec 27 21:19:29 2018
Local Time:  Thu Dec 27 21:20:29 2018
```

Comment: What is `seconds`? It seems like you're storing a variable and printing it twice. Variables in python won't update themselves...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` module to measure current time using [datetime.now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), then find the difference between the two current times

```
import datetime
import time

t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Local Time: ",datetime.datetime.now())
time.sleep(5)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Local Time: ",t2)
print("Time taken: ",t2-t1)
```

The output will be

```
Local Time:  2019-04-24 10:29:00.391341
Local Time:  2019-04-24 10:29:05.395949
Time taken:  0:00:05.004613
```

Answer (score 1):

the method ctime() converts a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string representing local time. If secs is not provided or None, the current time as returned by time() is used.

so try to remove seconds:

```
import time

print("Local Time: ",time.ctime())
time.sleep(60)
print("Local Time: ",time.ctime())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove seconds and it will work

```
import time

print("Local Time: ",time.ctime())
time.sleep(60)
print("Local Time: ",time.ctime())
```